# How a reexport a type in OCaml?

Tags: module, ocaml

Let's say I have a module `A` which is defined as such:

```
type foo = Bar | Baz
```

a module `B`:

```
open A

let string_of_foo = function
    | Bar -> "bar"
    | Baz -> "baz"
```

and a module `C`:

```
open A
open B

let () =
    let f = Bar in
    print_endline (string_of_foo f)
```

How can I change the module `B` to reexport the type `foo` so that I don't have te open the module `A` in the module `C`?

Thanks.

Comment: You're searching for [include](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/modules.html#module-expr)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One easy way to re-export things in `B` is to include `A` in `B`:

```
(* b.ml *)
include A

let string_of_foo = function
| Bar -> "bar"
| Baz -> "baz"
```

By compiling this `b.ml` with `ocamlc -c -i b.ml`, you can see what is happening:

```
type foo = A.foo = Bar | Baz
val string_of_foo : foo -> string
```

The signature of type `foo` in `b.ml`, `type foo = A.foo = Bar | Baz` may confuse you since it is not very often seen in OCaml. It indicates that the type `B.foo` is not only having the constructors of the same names but also completely equivalent with `A.foo`.

Another way to reexport `A.foo` from `B` is to use this type definition:

```
(* b.ml *)
type foo = A.foo = Bar | Baz

let string_of_foo = function
  | Bar -> "bar"
  | Baz -> "baz"
```

This is useful when you want to reexpose only some of types defined in a module. (`include A` reexports everything defined in `A`.)

Do not forget writing `= A.foo`, otherwise `B.foo` becomes a different type from `A.foo` even though it has the same names.

With one of these changes, you can write `C` without referring `A` directly:

```
open B

let () =
    let f = Bar in
    print_endline (string_of_foo f)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning OCaml for 3 months for now so my answer may not be the best. But according to the book I started with: [Real World OCaml](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/index.html) it's not a good idea to open lots of modules. I would use dot notation, in your case:

a module `B`:

```
let string_of_foo = function
  | A.Bar -> "bar"
  | A.Baz -> "baz"
```

actually, only first `A.` is required to tell OCaml what type you have in mind. This one should work too:

```
let string_of_foo = function
  | A.Bar -> "bar"
  | Baz -> "baz"
```

But I prefer to be consistent.

and a module `C`:

```
let () =
  let f = A.Bar in
  print_endline (B.string_of_foo f)
```